# Is it safe to remove an original administrator user in Google Workspace?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I have an administrator and a normal user in my Google Workspace subscription.

I would not like to pay for two users when in fact I use only one.

I gave administrator rights for the normal user and set its e-mail address as the main contact for the Google Workspace.

Logging in to the admin console with the normal user now I am able to remove the original administrator user. Is it safe to do so? I would not like to lose my Google Workspace.

Comment: Rather than appending an update that adds a new question, please edit the question to focus is what is current inquiry and make the title more specific.

Comment: @Rubén I did. Is this now more clear?

Comment: Thank you. I haven't experienced your case but here is the help article about deleting an admin account -> https://support.google.com/a/answer/9011447?hl=en. You know that you can contact the official support, right? ->  https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en

Comment: Thanks indeed, these were indeed informative and helpful.